# How to support both json and html response with Spring Boot

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, restful-architecture

I want to send data to both mobile (using json) and web (using html) and I am using Spring boot. I want to attain similar architecture and functionality as used by facebook(graph.facebook.com and facebook.com) and twitter(api.twitter.com and twitter.com) . Also I am using Angular.js as a web framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing prevents you to make two different implementations (json, html) and serve it from same URL. Just use proper [Consumable Media Types](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-consumes) or [Producible Media Types](http://Producible%20Media%20Types) eg:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/pets/{petId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Pet getPet(@PathVariable String petId, Model model) {
    // implementation omitted
}
```

Comment: But I have to use separate urls for the two right. So how should I configure it if I am using Spring Boot.

Comment: I want to set separate urls of html and json response. Suppose baseurl for json is: http://api.myapp.com and base url for html data is http://myapp.com and now I want to create the above controller in Spring Boot. How shoud I set separate base urls for the same.

Comment: then make simply two controllers (or even two applications). and since you want to use different domain name, use reverse proxy like nginx.

Comment: nginx is a Web server and has nothing to do with Spring Boot.